# NUnit text output is not behaving

Tags: .net, unit-testing, automated-tests, nunit, nunit-3.0

I have the following test:

```
[Test]
public void LogTest()
{
    TestContext.WriteLine("Hello");
    TestContext.Error.WriteLine("Ergh");
    TestContext.Out.WriteLine("Out");
    TestContext.Progress.WriteLine("Is this progress?");
}
```

It should be writing out to the NUnit log (?).

When I run it with ReSharper, I only get the string `Hello` and `Out` displaying in the Unit Test Sessions window.

When it's run with NCrunch I don't get any output at all.

1. Why is this?
2. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of NUnit's Write statements write anywhere! They are turned into messages, which are then handled by the runner as events. The output is sent wherever the runner decides it should go.

This is even true for *Console.Write* in a test, since NUnit intercepts it.

For the runners you are using:

- Make sure you have the latest version of ReSharper. TestContext.Error and TestContext.Progress create a new message, which your version may not be handling. Contact the JetBrains folks to see what they support.
- For [NCrunch](https://www.ncrunch.net/), I'd also check the version you have. NCrunch tracks NUnit very closely and I'd be surprised if the latest version doesn't handle everything.

To see the messages for now, use the NUnit 3-console runner.

Comment: Thanks Charlie.  I'm using the latest versions of both (though I will double check that when I'm back in the office).